# Creating an Array with dynamically updated variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have some PHP variables whose names are directly linked to the function they contain.

Is there anyway of automating the creation of these variables, so that I can ALL variables 00-200 available for use?

This is what I'm doing now...

```
$regdays00 = is_user_reg_matured( 00 );
$regdays02 = is_user_reg_matured( 02 );
$regdays05 = is_user_reg_matured( 05 );
$regdays08 = is_user_reg_matured( 08 );
```

I'd love to be able to go:

```
small function that creates all $redays000 - $regdays200

if ( $regdays162) { "This has now used is_user_reg_matured(162)" }
```

Thank you!

Comment: *Just No!* Don't do that. Use arrays or something else, but don't create freaking 200 variables just with an incrementing number.

Comment: why in the world would you create that many variables, just use an array

Comment: I'm not familiar with arrays... can you give me an example?

Comment: @Scott Google `PHP array` and `PHP for` and read the manual page. These are some basic stuff so make sure you really understand them :) Your code will be way better that way.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is begging for a basic loop and an array.

Something like this perhaps:

```
$regdays = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++) {
    $regdays[$i] = is_user_reg_matured($i);
}
```

There you go. An array of 0 - 199.

```
if ($regdays[162]) { 
    echo "This has now used is_user_reg_matured(162)";
}
```

I highly recommend you do some reading up on arrays and loops. These are some basic PHP tools you very much need in your toolbelt!