# PHP Array that creates multiple <li> instances

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am creating a PHP menu system (for an education program) that has a whole lot of module numbers, if statements, etc.

What I would love to do is go:

```
'module_number' = 'NUMBER'
'module_name'   = 'NAME'
'module_url'    = 'URL',

'module_number' = 'NUMBER'
'module_name'   = 'NAME'
'module_url'    = 'URL',

'module_number' = 'NUMBER'
'module_name'   = 'NAME'
'module_url'    = 'URL', etc, etc
```

and that then creates a li element for each module above in the format:

```
<li>
    NUMBER
    <?php if (( NUMBER * 3 - 1 ) < $GlobalVariable ) { ?>
        <a href="URL">NAME</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        NAME    
</li>
```

Is there some way I can do that?

I assume it would be with arrays, etc but I am still learning.

---

EDIT:

Ok, I've got a multidimensional array happening (thanks for telling me what they are called so I could learn).

```
$daysregistered = 2;
$modules = array (
    array(0,'Thought Engineering Introduction','thought-engineering/'),
    array(1,'Leadership','thought-engineering/leadership'),
    array(2,'The Key to Velocity','thought-engineering/the-key-to-velocity'),
    array(3,'Master Level Communication','thought-engineering/master-level-communication'),
    array(4,'Priming for Opportunity','thought-engineering/'),
    array(5,'Quality','thought-engineering/'),
    array(6,'Your Most Critical Role as a Leader','thought-engineering/'),
    array(7,'Comprehensive Single System Perspective','thought-engineering/'),
    array(8,'Nexus Points & Income Time/Busy Time','thought-engineering/'),
    array(9,'Goals, Precession & Motion','thought-engineering/'),
    array(10,'Risk','thought-engineering/'),
    array(11,'Measurement','thought-engineering/'),
    array(12,'Bringing it All Together','thought-engineering/')
);

for ($row = 0; $row < 12; $row++) {
    $unlocked = ( $modules[$row][0] * 3 - 1 ) < $daysregistered;
    echo "<li>";
    if ( $unlocked ) { echo "<a href='".$modules[$row][2]."'>"; };
    echo "<span class='module_no'>".$modules[$row][0]."</span>";
    echo "<span class='module_descript'>".$modules[$row][1];
    echo "<span class='module_access";
    if ( $unlocked ) { echo " lock"; };
    echo"'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-";
    if ( ! $unlocked ) { echo "un"; };
    echo "lock";
    if ( ! $unlocked ) { echo "-alt"; };
    echo "' aria-hidden='true'></i></span></span>";
    if ( $unlocked ) { echo "</a>"; };
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Comment: You just asked a question a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37716211/3933332 and you got some links to read up on. Now I would highly recommend you to really give you some time to read them and play around with it. Because here you will need to use a multidimensional array and to understand them you first need to understand a basic array. (Maybe even google for some basic tutorial exercises with arrays)

Comment: For your question: The title doesn't need tags, such as PHP, because you already got tags to tag your question; The title should be like a "keyword summary" of your problem; In the question body itself you can try to be more specific and **show some effort**: show attempts and research which you have done, where you are, where you want to get and where you are stuck; At the end "Thank you!" is just noise and you can remove it from the question;

Comment: (Might be the best for right now to delete the question here; Give yourself some time to read and learn the new stuff from the old question; Doing some research for the new question; Read [ask] again; Because downvoted questions count against you)

Comment: Fair call. I'm trying it at the moment. Almost there. I am just experiencing an error will post as an edit.

Comment: That is what you should normally do before you ask a question. You code, you try stuff and you get stuck. You isolate the problem, debug, search and trial & error. Then if you don't make any progress and haven't found anything on the internet you read [mcve] and [ask] and write up your question.

Comment: Understood. Sorry about that. I didn't even know what arrays were called so my searching wasn't finding anything. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Fixed it!!!!! OMG so excited. Thank you for the links and patience :)

Comment: You're welcome. (Keywords like "array" is stuff which you pick up in a basic tutorial, so maybe you want to read/watch one or two tutorials; Always remember that asking on SO should be your very very last option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply certain program logic to several elements, it is best to use a loop of some sort - it prevents you from repeating yourself (*DRY*-Principle - "Don't Repeat Yourself").

PHP knows several loop constructs, [`while`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) and [`for`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) being the most common ones. However for arrays, especially if you do only plan to read, not write them, there is an easy looping instruction provided by PHP as well: [`foreach`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

`foreach($array as $element)` executes everything within the statement's body for every element in `$array`, the current element is accessible with `$element`.

So the easiest way for you to solve your problem is, to store every element inside an array, and use said `foreach` to loop over it (looping over an array is also called `iterating` over an array).

---

As your data is more complex than just one value, you cannot store it in an array directly. You first need to structure it in a way that allows you to store all 3 properties of each entry (`module_number`,`module_name`,`module_url`) in one variable.

The easiest option is to use [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). Those are arrays with named keys (instead of numeric indices). YOu could structure each of your entries like this:

```
$entry = array(); // Since PHP5: $entry = []
$entry['module_number'] = 'NUMBER';
$entry['module_name']   = 'NAME';
$entry['module_url']    = 'URL';
```

Using [array literals](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) this can also be written like this:

```
$entry = array (
    'module_number' => 'NUMBER',
    'module_name'   => 'NAME',
    'module_url'    => 'URL'
)  // in PHP5+ you can also use [..] instead of array(...) again
```

---

Now you can store multiple entries with this exact structure in one array, then use `foreach` to loop over it (remark: `$array[]=$entry` prepends a new entry to an existing array, it's equivalent to [`array_push($array, $entry)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)):

```
// create an empty array
$entries  = [];

// add data
$entries[]= [
    'module_number' => 'NUMBER',
    'module_name'   => 'NAME',
    'module_url'    => 'URL'
];
$entries[]= [
    'module_number' => 'NUMBER',
    'module_name'   => 'NAME',
    'module_url'    => 'URL'
];
$entries[]= [
    'module_number' => 'NUMBER',
    'module_name'   => 'NAME',
    'module_url'    => 'URL'
];

// loop over all entries
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo "<li>\n" . $entry['module_number'] . "\n";
    if (($entry['module_number'] * 3 - 1) < $GlobalVariable) {
        echo '<a href="' . $entry['module_url'] . '">' . $entry['module_name'] . "</a>\n";
    } else {
        echo $entry['module_url'] . "\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: OP just asked a question a few minutes ago and he didn't even know about arrays. So just providing him some code probably won't help him and will just damage the site. Since he can just copy&paste the code without even understanding it. Then he will come back and ask the next question to write him code.

Comment: @Rizier123 I didn't read your titles before I made the effort writing the code. Seeing how tihngsd are now, I ahve to agree with you. However now I already put some effort into answering the question, so I don't really feel like deleting it...

Comment: *comments

Damnit, can't english today

Comment: Yes. If you want you now can try to edit your answer and make it even more detailed trying to explain OP what is going on and maybe add some manual links for him to read up on.

Comment: @Rizier123 on it as we speak

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! I managed to figure it out, but I also tried your afterward and it worked perfectly too :) Thank you again!

Comment: @Scott For more explanation on ym code, read it again now after my edit