# Create multiple variables in loop?

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I need to create 2 variables, and 34 of each of them.

$found1 > $found34

$name1 > $name34

I tried creating them in a for loop, but they are not available outside the loop.

is there a simple way to create these globally in a php page ?

Here is the test I tried

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 33; $i++) {
  $found[$i] = "David".$i;
}

echo "Found 3: " . $found3;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you were using?

Comment: updated sample above

Comment: Similar question 20 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37716211/3933332

Comment: Thanks, so must be an array then ? (or should be i guess?)

Comment: You just access it with the right index, like `echo $found[3];`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

[DEMO](https://eval.in/586485)

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 33; $i++) {
  $found["found".$i] = "David".$i;
}

extract($found);

echo "Found 3: " . $found3;
```

Result:

```
Found 3: David3
```

So you need the key to be `found.$i` to get `found1`, `found2`,...

---

> **Remember:** You end up creating too many variables!! It is better to use array as array

It just takes two characters to call `$found3` as `$found[3]`